# Most compatible rich text editor for AJAX and JQuery dialogs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce

I'm looking for the most compatible rich text editor to use with a JQuery Dialog, and content that is loaded via AJAX.

I have managed to get tinyMCE playing nice with the dialog after a bit of work, but trying to get it to also work with ajax loaded content has become a real pain.

So, just wondering if anyone else has had any success with similar approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [CkEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)? It has a nice bridge to jQuery and it works quite satisfactorily in one of my projects.

Comment: Do you know how to reinitialize it after an ajax postback, where the textarea html is replaced?

Answer (score 1):

There are many real time editors aout there but the only REAL alternative in measures of functionality is [CkEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).